# Why can't I change the className of a defined element

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, classname

I simply want to remove one class of some elements without any framework like jQuery. 
First I tried it with a for(... in ...) than change ist to a for(var i...) but now I found out that not even a direct selection doesn't work.

With jQuery it works fine. But it's... let's say for explaining what jQuery does.

My Script:

```
[109] <script>
[110]   var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
[111]   console.log('Class "hidden" size: ' + hidden.length);
[112]   console.log(hidden[0].tagName);
[113]   console.log(hidden[1].tagName);
[114]
[115]   hidden[0].className = '';
[116]   hidden[1].className = '';
[117] </script>
```

The console log:

```
Class "hidden" size: 2
H1
FORM
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined(anonymous function) @ login.html:116
```

Why can I get the tagName of `hidden[1]` but not change its className  but for `hidden[0]`.

When I change the order to

```
[115]   hidden[1].className = '';
[116]   hidden[0].className = '';
```

so `hidden[1]` is before `hidden[0]` it works.

It looks like `var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');` will be run a second time when the first selected element has been changed and the `length` of the element getting smaller.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* NodeList which means the elements it contains changes as the DOM changes. You remove the relevant class name from an element in that set and the element will be automatically removed from the set.

For this reason you should iterate over the elements backwards:

```
for ( var i = hidden.length - 1; i > -1; i-- ) {
  hidden[ i ].className = '';
}
```

On the first iteration the collection will contain 2 elements (at indices 0 and 1). You remove the class from the element at index 1 and that element is removed from the collection. On the next iteration there is only one element left in the collection but since `i` has decremented to 0 you are able to reference it correctly.

**Edit**

As suggested in the comments you could also repeatedly modify `hidden[0]`:

```
while ( hidden.length ) {
  hidden[ 0 ].className = '';
}
```

Comment: Could you also just repeatedly apply `hidden[0].className = '';` to the first element until there are no elements?

Comment: @JosephYoung - Yep that would work too. I've added an example of that approach to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But when I use `document.getElementsByClassName('hidden')` only once and write the value in a variable, why does this happen?

Comment: @dede - Because you're simply assigning a reference to a live NodeList to a variable. The assignment doesn't do anything special.